# Read a line of code from class file

Tags: java, reflection

Given a `StackTraceElement.getLineNumber()`, is there a way to read the content of this line from a compiled class file? And even if it is possible to match the line, would the content of the class file will be "obfuscated" by the compiler?

For example if I had:

```
public void myMethod () {
    MyObj m = new MyObj ();   // can I reconstruct this line as String?
}
```

Comment: The compiled class file contains bytecode, not source code... Just read it from the source code file you have on disk.

Comment: And even if you decompiled it on the fly, the line numbers still wouldn't match.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Well, it would sort of be the other way around. Assuming the class has been compiled with line numbers in the bytecode (for debugging), then when decompiling you can search the bytecode for the line number first, then start decompiling at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *source* code is not contained by the *compiled* class file, which contains bytecode; so no, working only from the class file you can't reconstruct that line of code. It's possible to de-compile Java bytecode, of course, and a sufficiently well-built decompiler might reconstruct that line of code to a greater or lesser extent, but you'd have to have a decent decompiler. The end results may or may not look much like the original source code, depending on optimisations and such.

Answer (score 1):

you can include the source file into your war / jar file which you can read as a file. The bytecode only contains the line number not the actual code

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve the bytecode instructions from the class file (Foo.class), but not the String that represents the source code. However, given a source file and a line number, you could instead read the line from the source file (Foo.java), using standard file reading techniques.

To get an idea of the kind of information contained in a .class file, check out the [`javap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) tool. I suppose technically you could make a best guess at the source that compiled to that class, or run a decompiler on it, but line numbers won't match exactly, formatting would be totally different, and perhaps crucially, there would be no comments or annotations using source retention level.